# ManyToMany field values from queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

Suppose i have this model:

```
Class Item(models.Model):
    ...

Class ItemCollection(models.Model):
    ...
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    ...
```

Now i filter ItemCollection:

```
collection = RuleRequest.objects.filter(*some_filter*)
```

Now from the "collections" queryset i need to get all unique Items from ManyToManyField. This is easily done for a single object, but how to do it with queryset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking... but if you simply want to get unique Items filtered by ItemCollection the bellow should work:

```
Item.objects.filter(itemcollection__*somefilter*).distinct()
```

e.g if ItemCollection has active field

```
Item.objects.filter(itemcollection__active=True).distinct()
```

Comment: Hehe, so simple, i even feel ashamed :) Thank you.